# What's a good phrase for a "collection of the places someone wants to visit"?

Tags: phrase-requests

The context here is a *personal* collection of such things. 15 years ago I'd have called this a *travel file.* For a digital collection, that name doesn't feel right.

*Travel diary* would feel appropriate for a record or a schedule, but not a list of unscheduled aspirations. And of course, *travel guide* isn't right.

So far, the closest I've found is ***travel atlas.*** There's precedent for using the word *atlas* for digital collections of places. For example, the website [Atlas Obscura](http://www.atlasobscura.com/) is a guide to "the world's wondrous and curious places."

**Added:** This collection may *also* include a record places that have been visited. Information someone might refer to on their return, or might share with someone else visiting the same place.

Comment: Consider the term *wish list*.

Comment: We call this a bucket list. It can include things other than travel, such as parachuting or running the Boston Marathon, but visiting famous places tends to comprise a sizable chunk of people's bucket lists.

Comment: Destinations (places) of a lifetime.

Comment: I like these ideas. There's a spectrum of specificity here, from a list of ideas (wish list) to specific plans (itinerary). There's also a spectrum of "curated-ness", from lightly curated (atlas) to moderately curated (bucket list) to highly curated (itinerary).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[Itinerary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/itinerary)***:

> - a detailed plan for a journey, ***especially a list of places to visit***; plan of travel.

Dictionary.com

> - ***[An itinerary](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/itinerary)***  is your travel plan — where you will go and when you will be there.
> - If you make plans to fly to Paris from Beijing or take a train to Chicago from Mexico City, you will need an itinerary. That means you will have a plan that displays how you will get from point to point in your travels and when you will be at each point. This word comes from the Middle English itinerarius and is defined as being "about a journey." Itineraries can be really useful because if you give your mother yours, she will always know where you are!

(Vocabulary.com)

Comment: From Latin for "journey of roads," and refers to a travel document. I like it! Also like that it could allude to a wishlist, aspirationally.

Answer (score 5):

Worth noting is the phrase **bucket list** -- while it isn't quite the same as what you're asking, being a list of actions one wishes to perform rather than a list of places one wishes to see, people often include "go to ______" or "do _____ at _____" on their bucket lists. However, it's a very personal thing -- if it's meant to be "a collection of places someone wants to visit [so they can finish their project on time]", this doesn't fit. If you're looking for "a list of places someone wants to go [for fun]", then this fits very well.

Merriam-Webster [defines](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bucket%20list) it as:

> a list of things that one has not done before but wants to do before dying

With its origin and etymology given as

> from the phrase kick the bucket (to die)

Comment: Indeed, "See ___" or "Visit ___" or even "Climb ___" would be popular entries on a bucket list. @Phil Sweet mentioned it in a comment above. A bucket list is more curated than an atlas, and less than an itinerary. It also represents a higher level of commitment than an atlas or travel file: it's an aspiration.